# Vue JS - <tr> , <td> elements not getting rendered when passed to table component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, tr, vue-slot

I have registered a single file table component using vue.js as:

```
   <template>
        <div>
            <table class="table border">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>header 1</td>
                        <td>header 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <slot></slot>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {};
    </script>
    <style></style>
```

I want to use it as a representational component. When I try to pass tr and td elements to it in Laravel blade like:

```
<table-component>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
</table-component>
```

how I registered the component:

```
Vue.component(
    "table-component",
    require("./components/admin/TableComponent.vue").default
);
```

everything get rendered except row and data elements and the table gets out of form. here`s table content and elements after getting rendered in browser:

[table elements in browser picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTIcq.png)

I have read online articles and searched through Q/As but couldn`t find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's mentioned in the official docs [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats)

Also refer this issue for more clarity https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/204

Comment: Thank you @Naresh but, I don't get. I'm using correct elements ( tr and td ) in table slot.  btw, shall I register  components for tr and tds too or the way I`m using them is correct?